# How can I use MS Word tab to implement the this dialogue layout?

Tags: microsoft-word, browser-tabs, layout

I want to use WORD to layout a dialogue. I want the person name portion left aligned and the sentence portion left aligned too. If the sentence is too long to stay in one line, the start of the second line should have the same left bound as the first line. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the alignment pegs (I forget what they're called exactly -- please correct me) circled here:

[image]

You can then align each separate section to the left.

Comment: The middle peg indicates thes start of the 2nd and + line. So a Tab stop marker should be set in the Ruler also so the start of the "long text" can be aligned to the middle peg. That would make "Larry:[TAB]Long long long...".